# Jquery Mousehover to Mouse click

Tags: jquery, slider, slideshow

I have jquery code for image slideshow with tabs navigation. It is working & slides image on mouseHover of nav. I want it to work on Click of particular nav & show it's image

Working Demo - [www.myevio.com](http://www.myevio.com)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
        $(window).load(function () {
            $(function () {
                $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
                setInterval(function () {
                    $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');
                }, 5000);
                $('.banner-links-inner a').on({
                    'mouseenter': function () {
                        $('.fadein img').hide();
                        $('#' + $(this).data('id')).fadeIn();
                    }
                });
            });
        });//]]>  
    </script>
```

How do I make it work on Click instead of hover?

Comment: replace `'mouseenter'` with `'click'`, also remove `$(window).load(function ()` its not required

Comment: @Satpal Could have to prevent default behaviour of clicking anchor too and maybe trigger it once the animation has completed. Now it really depends what op is expecting which this question doesn't provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tryed with this?

```
 $('.banner-links-inner a').click(function () {
                        $('.fadein img').hide();
                        $('#' + $(this).data('id')).fadeIn();
                    });
```

instead using on?

or if you want to use on change to this:

```
$('.banner-links-inner a').on({
                    'click': function () {
                        $('.fadein img').hide();
                        $('#' + $(this).data('id')).fadeIn();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

change this `'mouseenter'` to this `'click'`

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by just replace

'mouseenter': function () {

with

'click': function () {

And remove href form anchor tag

```
<a  data-id="img1">POWEROCK 13600mAh Power Bank</a>
```